# An integration involving exponential and trigonometric terms

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Assuming $ d, r, f,c> 0 $, I am wondering how one could get the below integral analytically:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-d \: b^2) \frac{-b \: c \:\cos(b\: c) + (1 + b^2 f)\sin(b\: c)}{b + b^3 r^2} \,\mathrm{d}b$$

I used Mathematica to get this integral, but it could not take the integral.

Comment: Thanks, I did @LeeDavidChungLin

Comment: What make you think that a "closed form" expression exists ? Maybe by using Fourier Transforms ?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure if it exists or not! @JeanMarie